# How can the "Share of merchandise imports at current PPPs" be negative?

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp, international-trade

I'm looking at the [Penn World Table 9.0 data](https://www.rug.nl/ggdc/docs/pwt90.dta), and find that the "Share of merchandise imports at current PPPs" (`csh_m`) can be negative. For example,

```
   country  year  csh_m
   <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 Aruba   1970. -0.485
 2 Aruba   1971. -0.459
 3 Aruba   1972. -0.436
 4 Aruba   1973. -0.441
```

My initial thought is that the share of import (`csh_m`) here actually means "net import as share of GDP." However, this is not correct, because share of import (`csh_m`) and share of export (`csh_x`) don't have the same magnitude.

```
   country  year  csh_m csh_x
   <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Aruba   1970. -0.485 0.427
 2 Aruba   1971. -0.459 0.435
 3 Aruba   1972. -0.436 0.441
 4 Aruba   1973. -0.441 0.477
```

1. Where can I find documentation explaining the construction of `csh_m` and `csh_x` from the Penn World Table?
2. If a want to construct a variable of trade openness, should I add the absolute values of `csh_m` and `csh_x`?

Comment: Have you looked at p3 of http://www.rug.nl/ggdc/docs/national_accounts_in_pwt80.pdf ?  If it's only very small countries, could it be that statistical discrepancies are larger than imports?

Comment: All the `csh_m` (Share of merchandise imports at current PPPs) numbers in that table for all years and all countries are negative  (apart from some years for Bermuda) while all `csh_x` (Share of merchandise exports at current PPPs) are positive (again except for a few years for Bermuda).  These shares look like $Y=C+I+G+X-M+R$ all divided by $Y$. Places with big absolute values seem to include Hong Kong, Singapore, BVI, Malta, Turks & Caicos, where trade is indeed open.  So you could add the absolute numbers together

Comment: See https://www.rug.nl/ggdc/productivity/pwt/ and the legend tab of the Excel spreadsheet for more explanation about the data